# Limiting scope of Python import

Tags: python, namespaces

I have some code that looks like this:

```
from pyparsing import Word, alphas, Optional, ...
# Do stuff ...
# And at the end, save a result to the outside world.
parser = ...

# Now use parser but don't use anything else from pyparsing again.
```

I like having the convenience of calling `from <package> import <etc>`, but I only want it to be used in a very small segment of code. I am afraid I am contributing to namespace pollution because I have a number of small snippets like this in the same file.

What is the Pythonic way of handling this situation? I am still just kind of playing around with it, so I would rather not write and rewrite`pyparsing.` so many times.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One easy way is to use function scope to control import visibility within a file:

```
def prepare_parser():
    from pyparsing import Word, alphas, Optional, ...
    # do stuff, and get the final thing to return
    return ...

parser = prepare_parser()
```

Comment: The technique works and is easy to do, but it is uncommon and a number of developers would cringe at the practice of using a function to hide the imports from the global scope.  In short, I'm not sure this should be a recommended practice.  Putting imports inside functions is normally only done with the import needs to be delayed (doing the import when a function is called, not when a module is loaded).  I point this out because the OP is asking for Pythonic practices -- there are other techniques that get the job done without localizing imports.

Comment: @RaymondHettinger My impression is that the majority of developers simply don't bother to hide imports from the global scope. (Mostly either just dealing with the extra values in the namespace, or importing modules and using `<module>.<member>` notation, possibly with `as` aliasing.)

Comment: It really depends on whether you expect users to be running ``help(yourmodule)`` or ``dir(yourmodule)`` in order to discover the API.  Both of those API discovery techniques are impaired by namespace clutter.

Answer (score 12):

The usual ways to control namespace pollution are

1. Delete the variables after use
2. Use the __all__ variable
3. Use import-as to underscored variable names

These techniques are all used by the core developers in the standard library.  For example, the *decimal* module:

- starts out with [private name imports](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/decimal.py#l139) such as `import math as _math` etc.
- Later it does work to setup a threading environment followed by [variable deletion](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/decimal.py#l402) using `del sys, MockThreading`.
- In addition, it [defines an __all__ variable](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/decimal.py#l118) to make clear what the public API is.

Taken together, these techniques keep the namespace as clean as a whistle.